# How to resolve "Absent Code Attribute" error/exception in Spring Web Application?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am developing maven webapp using Eclipse, SpringMVC, Spring-Data-JPA, Spring-Security, Hibernate and Apache Tomcat 7.

I am getting 2 exceptions related to "Absent Code Attribute".Below are the exceptions:

1. **In applicationContext.xml**: Exception 'Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/persistence/RollbackException'. Near

   ```
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
   ```
2. **In security.xml**: Error occured processing XML 'Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/ServletException'. Near `<http>`

***pom.xml***

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.gaurav.jba</groupId>
<artifactId>java-blog-aggregator</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <org.springframework.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <apache.tiles>3.0.4</apache.tiles>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- JAVA EE6 WEB & JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- APACHE TILES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.tiles}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.tiles}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING FRAMEWORK -->
    <!-- Core utilities used by other modules. Define this if you use Spring 
        Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Expression Language (depends on spring-core) Define this if you use 
        Spring Expression APIs (org.springframework.expression.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core) Define 
        this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, 
        spring-beans) Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, 
        spring-beans) This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection 
        Container and is generally always defined -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, 
        Quartz, and Freemarker integration Define this if you need any of these integrations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-aop, spring-context) Define this if you use Spring Transactions or 
        DAO Exception Hierarchy (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, 
        spring-tx) Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA, 
        and iBatis. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx) 
        Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, 
        JiBX, Castor, XStream, and XML Beans. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-context) Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and 
        Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context) 
        Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another 
        web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC for Servlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet 
        Container such as Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC for Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
        spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Portlet 
        Container (org.springframework.web.portlet.*) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Support for testing Spring applications with tools such as JUnit and 
        TestNG This artifact is generally always defined with a 'test' scope for 
        the integration testing framework and unit testing stubs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <contextFile>src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml</contextFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

***applicationContext.xml***

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.gaurav.jba">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>

<jdbc:embedded-database type="HSQL" id="dataSource" />

<bean id="emf"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.gaurav.jba.entity" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" />
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.gaurav.jba.repository" />

<import resource="security.xml" />
```

***dispatcher-servlet.xml***

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.gaurav.jba.controller"></context:component-scan>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/defs/general.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
</bean>
```

***security.xml***

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/users**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/users/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.html" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Please help to resolve these 2 errors/exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Any particular reason to replace javaee-web-api with jboss-javaee-6.0?

Comment: Check [this](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/WhatsTheCauseOfThisExceptionJavalangClassFormatErrorAbsentCode)  for full description.

Comment: Hi. Above 2 issues got resolved. But now I am getting another error in security.xml:

Class 'org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils' is abstract

Comment: Can you post full stack ?

Comment: check this url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770789/spring-security-warning-class-authorityutils-is-abstract