# how to add a default admin user in spring security xml config?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I am trying to add a default admin user in the Spring Security 3 xml configuration, and I tried this ! but it says `Bad credentials`

Spring-security xml config:

```
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.xhtml"
        default-target-url="/dashboard.xhtml" authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml?incorrect=true" />
    <!-- authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml?failed=true" -->
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" delete-cookies="true"
        logout-success-url="/login.xhtml" />


</security:http>

<bean id="userDao" class="com.tds.erp.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl"
    autowire="default" />

<bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.tds.erp.services.impl.UserDetailServiceImpl">
    <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"></property>

</bean>

<bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="daoAuthenticationProvider" />

</bean>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <security:password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
    </security:authentication-provider>

    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="admin" password="admin"
                authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_RH, ROLE_MANAGER" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>

</security:authentication-manager>
```

so what's the problem, and how can I solve this

**==> EDIT <==**

I am using

- Spring security 3.2.7
- Spring 3.2.5
- Spring IDE STS 3.6.3

In my configuration I have this warning in name spaces :

> Class 'org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils' is
>   abstract

in this line :

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd"
```

and if I remove this :

```
 <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="admin" password="admin"
                authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_RH, ROLE_MANAGER" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
```

the warning is gone !!

how can I solve this ?

Comment: For the first part what does userDetailsService refer to?

Comment: you can see my edit, I added all spring security config

Comment: I deleted my original answer. Are you still getting the same problem ? I replicated this scenario using 3.2.7 with 2 in memory providers with the exact same config as yours .. It works alright for me .. Are you sure its not an issue with your UserServiceImpl(DAO Implementation)

Comment: there is no problem with the DAO implementation and it's working fine, but with the default users not working, and I have this problem in my configuration `Class 'org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils' is abstract` and I dont know what's the problem

Comment: @ArunM: you can see my edit

Comment: hmm .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770789/spring-security-warning-class-authorityutils-is-abstract . .The warning seems to be a non issue ..

Comment: Did you enable spring debug logs and see whats going on ? ..

Comment: I followed your link and I did an update of Spring STS and the warning is gone, but it can't login with my default user :(